# MATLAB sin() vs sind()

Tags: matlab, degrees, radians

I noticed that MATLAB has a `sin()` and `sind()` functions.
I learnt that `sin()` accepts the angle in radians and `sind()` accepts the angle in degrees.
The only difference I know is `sind(180)` gives 0 but `sin(pi)` doesn't:

```
>> sin(pi)
ans =
  1.2246e-016
>> sind(180)
ans =
     0
```

What boggles me is whether there is any scenarios or guidelines to choose between using `sin()` or `sind()`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any valid reason radians are used as the inputs to trig function in many modern languages?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147235/is-there-any-valid-reason-radians-are-used-as-the-inputs-to-trig-function-in-man)

Comment: @Magla I do not feel this is a duplicate case: the questions are strongly related but are not the same. Question here is of practical nature.

Answer (score 11):

From the documentation of `sind`:

> For integers `n`, `sind(n*180)` is exactly zero, whereas `sin(n*pi)`
>      reflects the accuracy of the floating point value of `pi`.

So, if you are extremely troubled with the fact that `sin( pi )` is not **precisly** zero, go ahead and use `sind`, but in practice it is just a wrap-around `sin` so you actually add a tini-tiny bit of overhead.

Personally, I prefer the elegance of radians and use `sin`.

Comment: I fear that kids that use MATLAB in highschool won't survive to graduation.

Comment: @EitanT I fear that kids that use dgrees instead of radians won't survive graduation... ;)

Comment: Why so much hatred for degrees?  In some applications degrees are the norm, and make more sense than radians.  I'm not sure why you feel the need to insult the intelligence of somebody who computes the sine of 8 degrees instead of 2*pi/45 radians.

Comment: @nispio try [Euler's identity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_identity) with degrees... Radians are of natural-physical nature, while degrees are artificail (why 360 degrees in a circle? why not 400 or 100 or...??).

Comment: The same class of arguments can be made against feet, inches, gallons, etc., but that does not mean that intelligent people never have to work with those units...